# How to use basic authentication in IIS7 with web.config with exception for ip range?

Tags: exception, authentication, iis-7

I need some basic authentication on IIS7 server, but i don't want it to show up from the range 192.168.0.x .

For .htaccess it would be something like:

```
Deny from all
Order deny,allow

AuthName "myauth"
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
Allow from 192.168.0.
Satisfy Any
```

Thx~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could something like this work?:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="..">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>

        <authentication>
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
          <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>

        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false"> 
          <add ipAddress="192.168.100.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0" allowed="true"/>
        </ipSecurity>

      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```